# Programmatically set PIN/Password used to unlock device

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6

Our software allows the users to lock their Windows mobile 6 devices using the following API call.

```
    [DllImport("aygshell.dll")]
    public static extern int SHDeviceLockAndPrompt();
```

When deploying our software our client would like to be able to set a universal unlock PIN/Password for all of their users so that each device does not need to be set-up manually.

Is there any way to set this either programmatically or through a reg key?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the Shell function call you have mentioned. But [Local Authentication Sub System (LASS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms926467.aspx) Application Development should help you in doing this. Secondly it is most secure device mechanism for windows mobile 6.5 and earlier versions.