# transfer/transform data from XML/XSD to database using XSLT

Tags: xml, postgresql, xslt, xsd, rdbms

I have been given an XML file to store it in the form of a database(postgresql, in linux environment). 
I had no experience and knowledge of doing this before. but when I had a [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138575/how-can-i-create-database-tables-from-xsd-files) on this, I realized that something called XSLT is what I am looking for.
I have managed to draw XSD(using oxygen xml tools) from the XML file.

Could you please suggest me a tutorial where I can find a quick solution to my specific needs?

it is prefered that a click would do both db/tables creation as well as dumping the data. But if that also calls for a big headache, I can create the db and tables(with the help of the XSD file I just extracted) and then have your kind help to transfer data from XML to database.

Comment: wow, no answers after 3 hours. thats a record! perhapse it is the timezone. everyone is sleeping

Comment: 3 hours is nothing, I've had this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7580452/108847 open for 7 months without answer and there are many older questions on SO :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by ``a click'', what's wrong with writing an xslt stylesheet that does the job for you?

Comment: I think the question is too broad, it is difficult to answer with anything else than a list of books and tutorials (as Dimitre just did)

Answer (score 1):

> Could you please suggest me a tutorial where I can find a quick
>   solution to my specific needs?

I don't believe you'll find "a quick solution to your specific needs" anywhere, but have a look at the resources listed in this answer:

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589**